# Vector equation of a line segment

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I'm learning about finding the vector equation of a line segment from $\vec{r_0}$ to $\vec{r_1}$ from the 6th edition of Calculus, Early Transcendentals by James Stewart (page 797), where it's stated \begin{align*}\textbf{r(t)}=(1-t)\textbf{r}_0+t\textbf{r}_1, \ \ \ 0\leq t \leq 1 \end{align*}
and I'm not following the reasoning given. They sort of jump from $\vec{r}=\vec{r_0}+t\vec{v}$ to the equation above, only providing that the direction vector $\vec v = \vec{r_1}-\vec{r_0}$ which I don't follow either, partly because I'm not exactly sure what $r_1$ is supposed to represent.

Comment: “not exactly sure what $\vec r_1$ is supposed to represent” It’s a point in space, and $\vec v = \vec r_1 - \vec r_0$ is the vector from the point $\vec r_0$ to the point $\vec r_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}\textbf{r(t)}=(1-t)\textbf{r}_0+t\textbf{r}_1, \ \ \ 0\leq t \leq 1 \end{align*}$$ is the same as $$\begin{align*}\textbf{r(t)}=\textbf{r}_0+t\textbf({r}_1-{r}_0), \ \ \ 0\leq t \leq 1 \end{align*}$$
As you notice the line starts at  $\textbf{r}_0$ and extend in the direction of $\textbf({r}_1-{r}_0)$

You may think of $\textbf{r}_0,  \textbf{r}_1, \textbf{r}(t)$ as vectors in standard form that is vectors with inial points at the origin and the terminal points on the desired line.

Comment: I just thought of a question. I always thought the difference between two vectors starting with $r_1$ and extending to $r_0$ was the displacement vector. In my mind I'm not just seeing $r_1-r_0$ as a direction vector, but also as the displacement vector. Is the magnitude of this vector the same as the magnitude of the line segment?

Comment: Yes it is the magnitude of the segment..